# вопрос с массивами

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

решаю задачу и результаты теста показывают что я где-то намудрил с массивами (насколько я понимаю), но я не вижу где  мог бы допустить ошибку. Знатоки, подскажите!)

```
public class Kata {

    public static int findShort(String s) {
        String [] words = s.split(" ");
        String shortestword = words[0]; 

        int size = shortestword.length();
        for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {

            if (words[i].length() < shortestword.length()) { 
                shortestword = words[i];     
            }
            return shortestword.length();
        }
    return 0;
    }
}
```

результаты теста показывают

> expected:<3> but was:<4>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Табулируйте! Яснее будет ошибка.
Проблема становится очевидной:

```
public class Kata {
  public static int findShort(String s) {
    String [] words = s.split(" ");
    String shortestword = words[0]; 
    int size = shortestword.length();
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
      if (words[i].length() < shortestword.length()) { 
        shortestword = words[i];     
      }
      return shortestword.length();
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Вы не проходите цикл до конца. При первой же итерации у вас выполняется возврат функции. Правильно:

```
public class Kata {
  public static int findShort(String s) {
    String [] words = s.split(" ");
    String shortestword = words[0]; 
    int size = shortestword.length();
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
      if (words[i].length() < shortestword.length()) { 
        shortestword = words[i];     
      }
    }
    return shortestword.length();
  }
}
```

Однако, есть ещё ошибка: вы делаете цикл неправильное количество раз, а точнее, столько, сколько букв в первом слове (size). А стоит делать words.length() раз.

Comment: первый раз писал сюда проблему, не разобрался еще с табуляцией) спасибо, решение помогло!)

Comment: Табуляция нужна не столько нам, сколько вам поможет отлавливать такие проблемы :)